# Rails Order By Polymorphic Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have the following models:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    has_ancestry cache_depth: true, orphan_strategy: :destroy

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :shortcuts
    belongs_to :itemable, :polymorphic => true, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :itemable

    attr_accessor :key

    def key
        self.itemable.key
    end
end

class Folder < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :item, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item
end

class Field < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :item, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item
end
```

And I want to be able to order the results by the :key attribute on itemable (both folder and field have the attribute called :key), I.E.

```
Item.all.include(:itemable).order("itemable.key ASC")
```

I figured out a way to do wit through attr_accessor, but not sure if this is the right way:

```
Item.all.sort_by(&:key)
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort it in this specific way, if I may ask? Have you checked the database what specific field contains the key? If you write pure SQL (like in the order clause), it should work if you pick the correct fieldname.

Comment: _"I figured out a way to do wit through attr_accessor"_ - It will work even if you remove `attr_accessor :key`. You have already defined a method `key`. The same method can also be defined as `delegate :key, to: :itemable` btw.