# Rails polymorphic entries - sort by external field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have actors who can have a role in a movie or in episodes of TV shows - my application treats these different and hence I have a model "Role" that is polymorphic.
When I display an actor, I want to show two tables - one with all the movies they star in (sorted by movie title) and one with all the episodes they star in (again sorted by title). I am not sure how I access the "external" title field to do so.
There must be something like @actor.roles.sort_by..... ?

Model: Actor

```
class Actor < ApplicationRecord
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :first_name, uniqueness: { scope: :last_name }

    has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :movies, through: :roles, :source => 'castable', :source_type => 'Movie'
    has_many :episodes, through: :roles, :source => 'castable', :source_type => 'Episode'
...
```

Model: Role

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :actor
  belongs_to :castable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Model: Movie

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    has_many :roles, as: :castable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :actors, through: :roles
    ...
```

Model: Episode

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :roles, as: :castable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :actors, through: :roles
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found parts of the answer [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501385/rails-order-by-polymorphic-attribute). Not sure how elegant this is, but it works :)